# Fixed points of automorphism in the field $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am trying to solve a problem, and one of the parts is the following:

Let $M=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
a&b\\ c&d
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ be a non singular $2\times 2$ matrix with integer entries, $L=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ the field of complex rational functions in two indeterminates. Let $\phi:L\rightarrow L$ be the endomorphism that fixes the complex numbers and  $\phi(x)=x^ay^b$, $\phi(y)=x^cy^d$. Suppose that $\det M=\pm 1$.

> Show that $\phi$ has a non constant fixed point iff one of the eigenvalues of $M$ is a root of $1$.

I observed that $\phi(\phi(x))=x^{a^2+bc}y^{ab+bd}$ and $\phi(\phi(y))=x^{ac+cd}y^{bc+d^2}$, and
$$(1\;\;0)M^2=(a^2+bc,ab+bd),\qquad (0\;\;1)M^2=(ac+cd,bc+d^2)$$
By induction we can derive the expressions for $\phi^{(n)}(x)$ and $\phi^{(n)}(y)$. Suppose one of the eigenvalues of $M$ is a $k$-th root of 1. Thus $1$ is an eigenvalue of $M^k$, and since $\det M=\pm 1$ the other is $\pm 1$. If it's $1$ then $M^k=id$ otherwise $M^{2k}=id$. Thus there exists an integer $h$ so that $\phi^{(h)}=id_L$. So $\phi$ has finite order  in the group of automorphisms of $L/\mathbb{C}$.

Then I tried to infer something about the fixed field of $\phi$ but with no success...
(It might be helpful that in one of the previous parts I had to show that $\phi$ is an automorphisms iff $\det M=\pm 1$)

Comment: Hmm. What do you do, if 
$$M^k=\pmatrix{1&m\cr0&1\cr}$$ for some non-zero integer $m$. $\det M^k=1$, $1$ is an eigenvalue, but it is only a simple eigenvalue. It is a double root of the characteristic polynomial of $M^k$ though. I suspect that a different approach may be needed

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of $M$ is quadratic. The only roots of unity that satisfy a quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients are those of orders $1,2,3,4$ and $6$. Can you use that?

Comment: of course you're right, in the rush I forgot to study this case.