# Automorphism of $\mathbb C(x,y)$ and its order in $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb C(x,y))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, rational-functions

In the following problem

> Let $M=\bigg (\begin{matrix} a& b\\ c& d\end{matrix}\bigg )$ be a nonsingular matrix with integer coefficients and $L=\mathbb C(x,y)$.
>
> (i) Show that $\phi(x)=x^a y^b$, $\phi(y)=x^cy^d$ can be uniquely extended to a field homomorphism from $L$ to $L$, with $\phi|_\mathbb C=id$.
>
> (ii) Show that $[L:\phi(L)]$ (algebraic degree) is finite and that $\phi$ is an automorphism if and only if $\det M=\pm 1$.
>
> (iii) If $\phi$ is an automorphism, show that $\phi$ has non-constant fixed points if and only if $M$ has an eigenvalue which is a root of unity.
>
> (iv) In the situation of (iii), show that either $\phi$ is conjugate to $\pm\bigg(\begin{matrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\bigg )$ or $\phi^{12}=id$.
>
> (v) Show that, if $K$ is the set of the points fixed by $\phi$, then $K$ is a field and $\mathrm{trdeg}(K/\mathbb C)$ is $1$ or $2$ ($1$ in the first case of (iv), and $2$ in the second case).

I have some problems in understanding "$\phi^{12}=id$". I solved the whole problem and demonstrated, instead of that, that if $\phi$ is not conjugate to the given Jordan block, then it has diagonal form and its eigenvalues are roots of $1$ or $-1$ (of the same order), and therefore that $\phi^n=id$ for some $n$: but why 12?

However, my statement of point (iv) allows me to prove point (v) too.

Comment: There might be some overlap with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329755/fixed-points-of-automorphism-in-the-field-mathbbcx-y?rq=1 (look at the comments, I believe something might help you)

Comment: Thank you very much: the following comment is indeed useful, but why is this true? "The only roots of unity that satisfy a quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients are those of orders 1,2,3,4 and 6."

Comment: "The only roots of unity that satisfy a quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients are those of orders 1, 2, 3, 4, and 6" because the minimal polynomial (over $\mathbb Q$) of a primitive $n$th root of unity is the corresponding cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n$, which has degree $\varphi(n)$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).  Now you just need to show that, if $n$ is not one of the orders mentioned, then $\varphi(n) > 2$.  (As a hint, look at the prime factorisation of $n$.)